# Use of pointers in a typedef struct which contains a string of characters

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, typedef

I want to write a function called "substitution" that passes as parameters:

1. a linked list "l" which has a character on each node ("lchar").
2. a string of characters "CHG"
3. a character "CH"
4. a "vec" structure that contains the final string.

The function scans each character at time on the linked list, and writes on "vec" the characters of the linked list which are different from the character CH passed as a parameter, but when it scans the exact CH character on the linked list, it writes on "vec" the string "CHG".

The following is the solution given by my textbook. I seem to understand the overall program, but  I can't understand the passage when the function scans the character CH:

`svec->v[cur]='\0'; strcat(svec->v,CHG);`

What does it do exactly? Why are we using pointers for "svec"? Why it is written `svec->v[cur]=l->lchar;` since we are handling a string of characters?

Solution:

```
struct el {
    struct el *next;
    char lchar;
};
struct el *l=NULL;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    char *v;
} vec;
vec svec;

int substitution (struct el *l, char *CHG, char CH, vec *svec) {
    \\ initialize svec in the dynamic memory
    int cur=0;
    while (l!=NULL) {
        if (l->lchar !=CH) {
            svec->v[cur]=l->lchar;
            cur++;
            l=l->next;
        } else {
            svec->v[cur]='\0';
            strcat(svec->v,CHG);
            cur=cur+strlen(CHG);
            l=l->next;
        }
    }
    svec->v[cur]='\0';
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svec->v[cur]='\0'; strcat(svec->v,CHG);
```

This replace the char at [cur] position on the svec->v char* with a terminating null byte in order to use strcat on it.

From **man strcat :**

> The  strcat()  function  appends the src string to the dest string, overwriting the terminating
>          null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a terminating null byte.

If the "dest char *" of strcat lacks terminating null-byte, strcat behavior is unpredictable. It serves as a security.

```
 svec->v[cur]=l->lchar;
```

It is written like that because "svec" and "l" are pointers, hence, you need to deference them in order to access their data.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated :)